# "Empty trash" command in WinSCP

Tags: command-line, ftp, file-management, winscp

I'm fairly new to WinSCP. I love having the "trash" feature, but of course I also want to occasionally quickly empty that "trash".

What would be a quick custom command to do that?

I believe this removes everything including the directory itself I'm right-clicking on:

```
test "!?Do you really want to delete ?no!" == "yes" && rm -rf !&
```

...but it would be great if I didn't have to delete and re-create the directory (since WinSCP doesn't automatically create it, when I delete a file and a /tmp directory is not present).

Would this work?

```
test "!?Do you really want to delete ?no!" == "yes" && rm -rf !&/*
```

I don't want to try it and accidentally delete everything in my root folder or something!

Any ideas?

Comment: question to moderators or expert users: does this question belong here or should it rather be on Stack Overflow?

Comment: What's the point of `!&/*`? Use a fixed path to the recycle bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete only files in the recycle bin, using `rm /path/to/recycle/bin/*`.

A full custom command would be like:

```
test "!?Do you really want to delete ?no!" == "yes" && rm /path/to/recycle/bin/*
```